# Flickr API always returning the same data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I have a small weather app. I get the weather data via "POST" request and append it to the document, that works good.

The users can query the weather by City, now I wanted to load an image of that city with a separate jQuery $Ajax() request.

However, I always get the same result.

The app relevant app structure looks like this:

```
 <input id="getIt" name="cityajax" type="text" class="ghost-input" 
 placeholder="Enter a City" required> // get user input, querying a city
 <button id="submit">Submit</button>

         <span class="humidLogo">Current humidity:</span> <i class="fas fa-temperature-low" ></i>    <span class="apiHumidity"> % </span>


       <div class="FlickResponse"></div> // flickrResposnse gets appended here
   </div>
```

The CSS is not relevant, so I follow up with the relevant JS function right away:

```
var destination = $("#getIt").val(); // cache the user input, I am not sure I have to listen for a change event here and then update the state.
var flickerAPI =
  "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&tags=" +
  destination; // the url to get access the api

$.ajax({
  url: flickerAPI,
  dataType: "jsonp", // jsonp
  jsonpCallback: "jsonFlickrFeed", // add this property
  success: function(result, status, xhr) {
    $(".FlickResponse").html(""); // here I want to empty the contents of the target div, but this never happens
    $.each(result.items, function(i, item) {
      $("<img>")
        .attr("src", item.media.m)
        .addClass("oneSizeFitsAll")
        .appendTo(".FlickResponse");
      if (i === 1) {
        return false;
      }
    });
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr);
    $(".FlickResponse").html(
      "Result: " +
        status +
        " " +
        error +
        " " +
        xhr.status +
        " " +
        xhr.statusText
    );
  }
});
```

That is all. So why do I always get the same response from the API? Do I have to listen to change events on the input field? Because the POSt request work without a change event listener.

Is it because I am querying 2 APIs and I am using the same input field for the value(stupid question, but you never know x).?

Here is a Codepen with the full code, just enter a city and click the submit button:

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/qLgRvp?editors=1010

Comment: I don't think your ajax function is actually being called by your submit event. I believe the function should be called within ' $("#submit").click(function (e)'

Comment: @Mo A, lol thanks sorry for this question.

Comment: Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pull the image retrieval (and weather lookup) into another function as shown below, then you're good!

I've forked to another codepen: [updated example](https://codepen.io/tlennox/pen/MZdvLy)

```
function loadDestinationImage() {
    var destination = ($("#getIt").val());
    var flickerAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&tags=" +  destination;
    $.ajax({
        url: flickerAPI,
        dataType: "jsonp", // jsonp
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonFlickrFeed', // add this property
        success: function (result, status, xhr) {
            $(".FlickResponse").html("");
            $.each(result.items, function (i, item) {
                $("<img>").attr("src", item.media.m).addClass("oneSizeFitsAll").appendTo(".FlickResponse");
                if (i === 1) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr)
                $(".FlickResponse").html("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
        }
    });
}
```

I'd do the same with the weather:

```
 function loadWeather() {
    var destination = ($("#getIt").val());

    $.post("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
    destination +
    "&units=metric&appid=15c9456e587b8b790a9092494bdec5ff",
    function (result, status, xhr) {

        var APIresponded =  result["main"]["temp"];
        var APIweather =  result["weather"][0]["description"];
        var sunGoing = result["sys"]["sunset"];
        var output = destination.capitalize();
        var humidValue = result["main"]["humidity"];
        var windy = result["wind"]["speed"];
        var windDirection = result["wind"]["deg"];

        if (windDirection <= 90) {
          windDirection = "southwest"
        }
        if (windDirection <= 180) {
          windDirection = "northwest"
        }
        if (windDirection <= 270) {
          windDirection = "northeast"
        }
        if (windDirection <= 360) {
          windDirection = "southeast"
        }
        if (APIweather.includes("snow")) {
          $('#displaySky').addClass('far fa-snowflake');
        }
        if (APIweather.includes("rain")) {
          $('#displaySky').addClass('fas fa-cloud-rain');
        }
        if (APIweather.includes("overcast")) {
          $('#displaySky').addClass('fas fa-smog');
        }
        if (APIweather.includes("sun") || APIweather.includes("clear")) {
          $('#displaySky').addClass('fas fa-sun');
        }
        if (APIweather.includes("scattered")) {
          $('#displaySky').addClass('fas fa-cloud-sun');
        }
        $("#message").html("The temperature in " + output + " is : " + APIresponded + " degrees. The sky looks like this: ");
        $(".apiHumidity").text(humidValue + " %");

        $('.apiWind').html(windy + 'km per hour. The wind direction is  ' + windDirection);
        console.log(APIweather);
    }

    ).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " +
        xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    });
}
```

And call from the submit function:

```
$("#submit").click(function (e) {   
    loadDestinationImage();
    loadWeather();
});
```

Comment: Upvoted, accepted as correect answer because this code is now officially beautified. A pleasure to the eyes and though mine worked, (heck, there was an jsonp call anyway), this code is readable, extendable and many people who look this up will learn something. Beautiful.